# Why is avec needed for "avec quelques semaines en retard"?

Tags: grammaire

I saw this sentence:

> Je suis arrivée avec quelques semaines de retard.

I was surprised - I would have phrased this as *je suis arrivée quelques semaines en retard*.

What is *avec* doing here? I haven't seen it used this way before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the choice. Your phrasing is not the most common one but still valid:

> *Je suis arrivée quelques semaines **en** retard.*
> *Je suis arrivée **avec** quelque semaines **de** retard.*
> *Je suis arrivée **en** retard **de** quelques semaines.*
> *Je suis arrivée **avec** un retard **de** quelques semaines.*

[image]

***Retard*** doesn't mean "**late**" (which is *en retard*) but is more like "**lateness**" so *quelques semaines **de retard*** literally translates to "a few weeks **of lateness**".

Comment: That's a really excellent explanation, that last sentence is super helpful. Thank you.